# This code seems to give me the result in the if statement and else statement at the same time, why?

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello welcome to the Next-Day calendar");
Console.WriteLine("Please write down the day");
int day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int day_next = day + 1;

Console.WriteLine("Please write down the month number");
int month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Please write down the year");
int year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

switch (month) 
{
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
        if (day_next <=31 && day > 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The date is " + day_next + '/' + month + '/' + year);
        }
        if (day_next == 32) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The day is " + 1 + '/' + (month+1) + '/' + year); 
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (year % 4 == 0 && day_next <= 29 && day > 0 || year % 4 != 0 && day_next <= 28 && day > 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The date is " + day_next + '/' + month + '/' + year); 
        }
        if (year % 4 == 0 && day_next == 30 && day > 0 || year % 4 != 0 && day_next == 29 && day > 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The date is " + 1 + '/' + (month+1) + '/' + year); 
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
        }
        break;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        if (day_next <= 30 && day > 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The date is " + day_next + '/' + month + '/' + year);
        }
        if (day_next == 30) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The date is " + 1 + '/' + (month + 1) + '/' + year);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
        break;
    case 12:
        if (day_next <=31 && day > 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The date is " + day_next + '/' + month + '/' + year);
        }
        if (day_next == 32) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The day is " + 1 + '/' + 1 + '/' + (year + 1)); 
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
        }
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Error!");
        break;
}
```

> If I enter for example: day = 22, month = 2, year = 2015
>   It will write "The date is 23/2/2015" and the next line will write Error! can anybody explain this?

Comment: I would suggest you google for some simple and free tutorials on Control Statements focusing especially on `If Else` statements http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson03

Comment: The code is executing logically. Perhaps the second if should be an "else if" if you meant to continue the same logic.

Comment: Set a break point and step through it. See what lines are getting executed and which aren't.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `else if` to "chain" conditions::

```
if (day_next <=31 && day > 0) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("The date is " + day_next + '/' + month + '/' + year);
}
else if (day_next == 32) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("The day is " + 1 + '/' + (month+1) + '/' + year); 
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
}
break;
```

What's happening is the first `if` statement is true, and executes - the next `if` statement is false, so it executes the `else`.  Using `else if` effectively chains the statements so they work more like a `switch`.

It's equivalent to:

```
if (day_next <=31 && day > 0) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("The date is " + day_next + '/' + month + '/' + year);
}
else 
{
    if (day_next == 32) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The day is " + 1 + '/' + (month+1) + '/' + year); 
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error!");
    }
}
break;
```

I would note that there are *much* simpler ways to generate a date from month/day/year inputs, but that's the reason for the result you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought there was no "else if" in C# because my teacher said that there wasn't. Anyway it works now. Thanks again!

Comment: @DannyDamsky Well, in a sense it's not it's own operator - it's just inlining the `if` within the `else` block.  I've added to my answer to show what it;s equivalent to if braces were added.